# Move all files related to a Basename file in folders and subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I have this files into a folder:

```
Enero.01200.2019.txt
Enero.01200.2019.pdf
Enero.01200.2019.png
Febrero.03100.2019.txt
Febrero.03100.2019.pdf
Febrero.03100.2019.png
```

Inside of each .txt file I have a value that indicate the order was unpaid, what I need is clear the log folder for unpaids orders, for example I use this command to a output.sh for check before run:

```
find /log/users/ -name '*.txt' | xargs grep -l unpaid | awk '{print "mv "$1" /tmp/ }' >> clearlog.sh
```

What I need is to print for example this:

```
mv /log/users/Enero.01200.2019.txt /tmp/ && mv /log/users/Enero.01200.2019.pdf /tmp/ && mv /log/users/Enero.01200.2019.png /tmp/
```

If somebody have a better way to doit but asking for confirmation or a way to see what will move, I will aprecite it.

There is about 2,500 files to clear and I wont do a mess deleting wrong files.

Note: all txt files had a PDF and PNG related file. Im working in ubuntu 20.04 server

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to `find` (recursively descend) the directory - or are all the files at one level?

Comment: I dont know, I only have one level "/log/users/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the files are in a single directory level, would suggest a simple shell loop that conditionally moves the files based on the `grep` exit status, like

```
for f in /log/users/*.txt; do
  grep -q unpaid "$f" && echo mv -t /tmp/ -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.pdf" "${f%.txt}.png"
done
```

(remove the `echo` once you are happy that it's doing the right thing).

If you need to recursively descend the parent directory with `find`, then similarly

```
find /log/users/ -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
  for f do grep -q unpaid "$f" && echo mv -t /tmp/ -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.pdf" "${f%.txt}.png"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: Hi steeldriver, the solution works fine, I just need another option, is there a way to echo also the all line content, example the file Enero.202020.01.txt contains this line "CustomerID=405060 OrderStatus=unpaid" I need to echo all this line, thanks

Comment: @valeriacarrillo remove the `-q` option from the grep command - consider replacing it with `-m1` if you only want to echo the first match (and avoid processing the remainder of the file)